# Why is this url not opening using python but can be opened directly from browser?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

This is the code I wrote in python for opening a url.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import requests
from random import randint
import urllib.parse

class AmazonReviews():
    def __init__(self):
           self.headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}

    def open_url(self,url):
        values = {}
        data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode('utf-8')
        req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, self.headers)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        html = response.read()
        return html

   def fetch_reviews(self,all_reviews_link):
        try:
            url = "https://www.amazon.in" + all_reviews_link
            print(url)
            html = self.open_url(url)
        except HTTPError as e:
            print(e)

review = AmazonReviews()
review.fetch_reviews('/gp/profile/amzn1.account.AFBWOEM2CWLC7ZRQ7WK6FQYXH6AA/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_gw_btm?ie=UTF8')
```

I am passing url as such because in the main project this url is scraped using href attribute that gives the relative path.
If there is any method to get absolute url please suggest.

Output -

```
https://www.amazon.in/gp/profile/amzn1.account.AFBWOEM2CWLC7ZRQ7WK6FQYXH6AA/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_gw_btm?ie=UTF8
HTTP Error 404: NotFound
```

Link of the code
https://onlinegdb.com/SyFPXzWVI

Comment: Interestingly, `requests.get(url, headers=self.headers).status_code` is 403.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) instead:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) + "/chromedriver")
link = "https://www.amazon.in/gp/profile/amzn1.account.AFBWOEM2CWLC7ZRQ7WK6FQYXH6AA/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_gw_btm?ie=UTF8"
browser.get(link)
name = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="customer-profile-name-header"]/div[2]/span').text
```

**Output:**

```
Dheeraj Malhotra
```

Comment: Thanks for he solution.

I used similar code for getting this url and it worked 
/gp/profile/amzn1.account.AFBWOEM2CWLC7ZRQ7WK6FQYXH6AA/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_gw_btm?ie=UTF8'
Why is it not working for this case?
@Zaraki Kenpachi